# Excel: what would be the formula for adding numbers into vote count everytime a name is mentioned under the respective columns

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, spreadsheet

[image]

[image: attached error edit]

For example if a show is written under Column b which is equivalent to 3 points it should add +3 into the vote count column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `SUMPRODUCT()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `F2`

```
=SUMPRODUCT((E2=$A$2:$C$18)*(E2<>"")*TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE($A$1:$C$1," "),"("))
```

Fill Down for rest of the cells !

---

With Single Array formula that `Spills` hence no need to drag,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `F2`

```
=MAP(E2:E18,LAMBDA(x,SUMPRODUCT((x=$A$2:$C$18)*(x<>"")*TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE($A$1:$C$1," "),"("))))
```

---

Comment: I tried to change the formula according to my table, unfortunately it does not work, I do not know anything about excel programming.  but i must have done something wrong. please help thank you. 
 =SUMPRODUCT((F2=$B$2:$D$18)*(F2<>"")*TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE($B$1:$D$1," "),"("))
This is what i put in, tried it with the other Formula you gave too but it gives an error there too.

Comment: @Destroyer2super can you show me a screenshot of where you have applied the formula and it is giving you an error so I can understand what has gone wrong on your end. And what is your Excel version? Are you using MS365

Comment: I have attached, the screenshot in the main post and i am using MS365 yes, thank you.

Comment: @Destroyer2super I don't think there should be any problem can you tell me, have you exported this data from any external source, `#N/A` means its not present in the data, though it does, may be there are non printable characters or whitespace characters

Comment: I did copy paste some text from discord ? Perhaps that is the issue?

Comment: Ah yes that could be an issue, can you share a copy like a onedrive link of the workbook, let me know what illegal characters are there

Comment: @Destroyer2super Can you please check now it is working, the header `(1 Point)` had a space before the first bracket

Comment: Tysm it seems to work, I  understand the gist of the formula and i will be able to use it to fill the rest of the table.

Comment: @Destroyer2super alright glad to know that it has worked for you =)